# Searching for a book about accidentally traveling to a different dimension

Tags: story-identification

I’ve been looking for this book for sometime now. All I remember was it was about a kid in school who went on a field trip to maybe New York and accidentally fell into a different dimension. Something about seeing the McDonald’s logo green instead of yellow. And then trying to return house but it not being his house. I’ve been trying to find this for 10 plus years.

Answer (score 13):

[Interworld by Gaiman and Reeves](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/InterWorld)

**All I remember was it was about a kid in school who went on a field
trip to maybe New York and accidentally fell into a different
dimension. Something about seeing the McDonald’s logo green instead of
yellow**

> On a field trip set by his Social Studies teacher, Mr. Dimas, Joey
> finds himself lost in the city, and then enters a strange fog; when he
> emerges, everything has changed. All the cars are brightly coloured,
> and the police cars are flashing green and yellow instead of blue and
> red. When he goes back to his home, he discovers that he does not
> exist anymore; instead, there is a girl named Josephine living there

From this [review](https://kellyrfineman.livejournal.com/247666.html)

> Crossing the street through some fog, Joey manages to cross into an
> alternate world. One where the McDonalds outlet has a tartan (shades
> of Coming to America!), and emergency lights flash green and yellow
> instead of red and blue

.